# Are questions about human evolution on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are questions about human evolution on topic?

Example (inspired by [Why have 2 bones in lower arm/leg and only 1 in upper?](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/4550/43))

> We only have **one** bone in our upper arm (the humerus) and upper leg (the femur) and **two** bones in the lower arm (radius and ulna) and lower leg (tibia and fibula). *Why* is this?

Comment: Shouldn't this (`Are questions about human evolution on topic?`) be a question for Meta?

Answer (score 4):

Biology SE has tags for both *evolution*:

> Changes in the heritable attributes of populations of organisms over time. Major mechanisms include drift, natural selection, mutation, and gene flow (migration).

and *human evolution*:

> The study of evolution with a particular focus on questions about the evolution of modern humans. Questions often incorporate the study of our nearest ancestors, both the extant primates and extinct pre- Homo sapiens.

Under the second tag, similar "why this and not that" questions have been answered, such as this one:

[Why do we blink instead of winking each eye independently?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/43010/why-do-we-blink-instead-of-winking-each-eye-independently)

I'd say that these questions are not about human health per se, and therefore are off-topic. They are about a biological process (evolution) and belong to biology SE.